# Returning a method in PHP

Tags: php, function, return-value

I have a class called `Converter`

```php
class Converter {
  public function convert($value, $from, $to){
    $this->switchUnitCall($from)($value, $to);
  }

  private function switchUnitCall($from){
    switch($from){
      case 'm':
        return $this->fromM; break;
      case 'km':
        return $this->fromKM; break;
    }
  }

  private function fromM($value, $to){}
  private function fromKM($value, $to){}
}
```

I want to return the private method called `fromM` or `fromKM` to its caller, so I can call the `fromM` with my another custom arguments inside the `convert` method.

When I run the code above, I got error `Undefined property: Converter::$fromM`

My question, is it possible to return a method in PHP? and how is it done? Thank you.

Comment: Is this your actual case or an example, it may be better to put the switch/case in the `convert` method rather than having to pass it around.

Comment: I would recommend using a callable in return that accesses by method name: https://3v4l.org/5tu01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return method but you can use method name to invoke it dynamically:

```php
class Converter {
  public function convert($value, $from, $to){
    $method=$this->switchUnitCall($from);
    $this->$method($value, $to);
  }

  private function switchUnitCall($from){
    switch($from){
      case 'm':
        return "fromM"; break;
      case 'km':
        return "fromKM"; break;
    }
  }

  private function fromM($value, $to){}
  private function fromKM($value, $to){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return your method, but keep in mind the visibility of a specific method, and from which scope they can be called. These two methods are private and can be called only within the given class.

The problem with this code is that you have called your methods as properties, thus the error for the undefined property.

They should be called like methods with parentheses and 2 mandatory passed `$this->fromM($value, $to)`, also you need to pass the arguments `$value` and `$to` to `switchUnitCall()` since they are mandatory too. 
Also, these two methods need to return a result:

```
 class Converter {
      public function convert($value, $from, $to){
        $this->switchUnitCall($from, $value, $to);
      }

      private function switchUnitCall($from, $value, $to){
        switch($from){
          case 'm':
            return $this->fromM($value, $to); 
            break;
          case 'km':
            return $this->fromKM($value, $to); 
            break;
        }
      }

      private function fromM($value, $to){
       //return conversion
      }
      private function fromKM($value, $to){
       //return conversion
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on your code I've to code redundant parameter for each case, it will take a long time instead of once when I call it.